# How to print the first link generated from find.All via Beautiful Soup?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import urllib
import requests


week_11_picURL = "https://www.packers.com/photos/game-photos-packers-at-vikings-week-11-2021#9258618e-e793-41ae-8d9a-d3792366dcbb"


response = get(week_11_picURL)
print(response)

html_page = requests.get(week_11_picURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')
image = soup.findAll('div', class_="nfl-c-photo-album__picture-wrapper")
```

Result:

```
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__picture-wrapper" data-id="146a902d-8de3-484b-ba55-1cf9d26b129c" data-name="Game Photos: Packers at Vikings | Week 11:1">
<button aria-label="Open Lightbox View" class="nfl-c-photo-album__enlarge-button" title="Open Lightbox View">
</button>
<picture><!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none; "><![endif]--><source media="(min-width:1024px)" srcset="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg 1x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_2x/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg 2x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_3x/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg"/><source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg 1x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_2x/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg 2x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_3x/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg"/><source srcset="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg 1x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_2x/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg 2x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_3x/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg"/><!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]--><img alt="211121-game-photos-2560" class="img-responsive" src="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg"/></picture>
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__picture-info">
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__progress">
<span style="">
                    1 / 129
                  </span>
</div>
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__football-divider">
<span class="nfl-o-icon nfl-o-icon--medium">
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="nfl-o-icon--football" viewbox="0 0 24 24">
<use xlink:href="#football"></use>
</svg>
</span>
</div>
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__copyright nfl-c-photo-album__copyright--centered">
                    Evan Siegle, packers.com
                  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__picture-wrapper" data-id="27ff497e-e149-45b7-b10a-19baa179e8a1" data-name="Game Photos: Packers at Vikings | Week 11:2">
<button aria-label="Open Lightbox View" class="nfl-c-photo-album__enlarge-button" title="Open Lightbox View">
</button>
<picture is-lazy="/t_lazy"><!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none; "><![endif]--><source data-srcset="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 1x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_2x/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 2x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_3x/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg" media="(min-width:1024px)"/><source data-srcset="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 1x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_2x/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 2x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_3x/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg" media="(min-width:768px)"/><source data-srcset="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 1x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_2x/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 2x, https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album_3x/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg"/><!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]--><img alt="211121-packers-vikings-1st-half-siegle-WM-001" class="img-responsive" data-src="https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/></picture>
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__picture-info">
<div class="nfl-c-photo-album__progress">
<span style="">
```

I want to be able to just print only the links generated from parsing this html. How would I go about doing so?

Speficially, I'm trying to highlight the link that comes immediately after "<source data-srcset="

Ex. this link

"https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 1x"

Answer (score 1):

***Please note*** there is a mix of `srcset` and `data-srcset` and also source occurs a few time in your soup. Also do not use `findAll()` in new code the newer syntax is `find_all()`.

#### How to fix?

However, you can select your target elements more specific with `css selectors`

###### Option #1

Focused only on the sources with `data-srcset`

```
data = [x['data-srcset'].split(',')[0] for x in soup.select('.nfl-c-photo-album__picture-wrapper picture source[data-srcset]:first-child')]
```

###### Option #2

Also include the source with `srcset`:

```
soup.select('.nfl-c-photo-album__picture-wrapper picture source:first-child')
```

Iterate over result set with `try` and `except` to avoid errors and append the results to a list:

```
data = []

for x in soup.select('.nfl-c-photo-album__picture-wrapper picture source:first-child'):
    try:
        data.append(x['srcset'].split(',')[0])
    except:
        data.append(x['data-srcset'].split(',')[0])
```

#### Example

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import urllib
import requests


week_11_picURL = "https://www.packers.com/photos/game-photos-packers-at-vikings-week-11-2021#9258618e-e793-41ae-8d9a-d3792366dcbb"


response = get(week_11_picURL)
print(response)

html_page = requests.get(week_11_picURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')

data = []

for x in soup.select('.nfl-c-photo-album__picture-wrapper picture source:first-child'):
    try:
        data.append(x['srcset'].split(',')[0])
    except:
        data.append(x['data-srcset'].split(',')[0])
        
data
```

#### Output

```
['https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/f_auto/packers/hjmcucejx2vmfshjkdkj.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/rgsvjp6sxu89ditolacv.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/zsogvqrqgaauqcdgejde.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/jyegqthuab2hsuygirqp.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/kwsq1fvn41f6kzqo4nkl.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/xludbah0g8oqlyvr7d0p.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/n6tkqlr65hv39hadt6tl.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/mhtylxhf2ito5f3y7cb7.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/an8onb7coak1psw7inp5.jpg 1x',
 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_new_photo_album/t_lazy/f_auto/packers/ttas30klcrtagdxnl2af.jpg 1x',
...]
```